# PROBLEM: Padding between bootstrap elements and card

Tags: html, css

I need to make padding between bootstrap elements and card, but Im able only to make paddings on bottom and top of the card not on the right and left side. How can I make space between them? Here is the code that I need to fix

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <img src="images/logo_mini.svg" hspace="5" style="width:35px;height:35px;">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">pslib.apps
    <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Práce</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Praxe</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown active">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Školní data
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Studenti</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Předměty</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Třídy</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Učitelé</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" style="margin:5px;">Zaregistrovat se</button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" style="margin:5px;">Přihlásit se</button>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
      <h6 style="text-align: left;font-weight:normal" class="alert alert-danger">Nesprávné heslo</h6>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-4">pslib</h1>
        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum.</p>
        <hr class="my-4">
        <p>Dolor.</p>
        <p class="lead">
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Registrace</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md"> <p>
    <div class="card">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
          <h3 class="form-text">Přihlášení</h3>
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">E-Mailová adresa</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Heslo</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Dlouhodobé přihlášení</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Přihlásit</button>
    </form>
  </p>
  </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="lbc.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="lbc.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="lbc.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bg-transparent text-lightgrey p-3 m-2">
                <p class="text-center">Designed in 2018 by pslib.cz</p>
        </div>
</body>     
</html>
```

code starts on line 61. Here is a picture how it should look like

[image: IMG HERE]

My code isnt finished yet but I need to solve the padding first, I also tried to put it in container but still nothing.

I hope someone can solve it because I have no idea how to resolve it...

Comment: What do you think about [Spacing Utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to add padding to your form like so:

```
<div class="card" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;">
```

Or if you want to move the whole card to left or right use:

```
<div class="card" style=" margin-left: 40px; margin-right: 40px;">
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

**Cau Matej,** firstly on line 61 u have unexpected `<p>` tag which givin' you an gap on top of the card. in `.card` i think it should has min 10px padding from each side if u wanna have the same look as on picture you provided. But in that case that u are using bootstrap system you have default margins and padding which is not always good because in this case you will have to overwrite `.col-md` because it has 15px from sides which not fit for you. My suggestion make your own layout using flex where you have full control of your code and layout